# PropertyGrid in Java Swing

Tags: java, .net, swing

Does Java Swing have a control similar to the PropertyGrid in .NET?

if so, which one is it? Or at least which one comes closest to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is not a built-in component for this, but there are several third-party projects. In particular, [Java-Bean-Examiner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/beanexaminer/) (GPL) looks promising.

[image: Java-Bean-Examiner]
[image: Java-Bean-Examiner]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=114041))</sub>

**Edit:** Also [L2FProd Common Components](https://web.archive.org/web/20150726091919/http://l2fprod.com/common/) ([Apache-licensed](https://l2fprod-common.dev.java.net/), which you may find more attractive than the GPL):

[L2FProd PropertySheet http://l2fprod.com/common/images/PropertySheetPanel.gif](http://l2fprod.com/common/images/PropertySheetPanel.gif)

Comment: I cannot for the life of me find any documentation that explains how to get the subcategories working.  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Fork L2FProd Common Components on [GitGub](https://github.com/sarxos/l2fprod-common)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) (Forms and Looks) to create your own property editor. It should be pretty quick to do and you can make it look much better than with the default Swing Look & Feel and layouts.