# Java PropertySheets

Tags: java, ejb

I have a java program that will work with a variety of Java Beans.  I'm interested in displaying a "property sheet" that will show the fields and methods for the bean from BeanInfo and/or reflection.  It could also update the information from the bean.

Is there a built-in way of creating these property sheets?  I was thinking something that would look like this: http://www.time-tripper.com/uipatterns/Property_Sheet.  Is this a good way to go about designing a simple beans application or does someone have a better alternative maybe with annotations?

Thanks!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842040/propertygrid-in-java-swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what most GUI designers (e.g. [NetBeans' Matisse](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)) will have for displaying the properties of Swing Beans. As NetBeans is open source, you can probably get what you're looking for there

Comment: Interesting idea.  I found the class http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-explorer/org/openide/explorer/propertysheet/PropertySheet.html.  But, I get a "NetBeans implementation of Preferences not found" exception when implemented as they suggested.  I could probably get it working, but it's a bit heavier than what I need.  Plus, I don't think the client will like having a GPL library in the project.

Comment: When you say "Property Sheet" - do you mean a web-page? Something that appears in the JConsole? A Swing panel? Is "Property Sheet" terminology from another language (c# perhaps?) - it's not immediately obvious what you want; after all, iterating thru a `BeanInfo` is hardly complicated...

Comment: I added a URL to the question.  It is more of a Microsoft thing, but as shown above NetBeans has it too.  It's basically just a JTable with a Name/Value tuple.  There's also a button that when pressed, a related widget is displayed to edit the value (eg DateChooser for values of type Date).  Thanks for you insights so far.

Comment: I see - yes; Java IDEs have had the same thing for 10 years but always for UI elements. They are called *customizers*

Comment: I found some data about Customizer:  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/Customizer.html.  Do you have a good tutorial?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not - it's been almost 10 years since I used them!

Comment: I'll vote up anyone who has a good tutorial or good modern-day alternative.