# Java Preference Manager

Tags: java, swing, preferences

I started implementing a solution for myself to manage user/application preferences, but then thought to myself there has to be a solution out there already. I started looking and found the [JFace API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace). I got excited, but then noticed it is designed to work with **SWT**. My application is written using **Swing**. I tried looking for a similar solution for Swing, but have not had any luck.

I'm looking for the equivalent of JFace for Swing (if that exists).

Is there a solution out there for managing preferences like JFace in Swing?

Comment: Would [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) do?

Comment: That's more of the backend part (which is part of what I'm looking for), but I'm looking for the frontend part as well. Such as [PreferenceDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/package-summary.html)

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842040/propertygrid-in-java-swing ?

Comment: No, that still requires me to write all the user interface code. Maybe there just isn't a Swing equivalent of _JFace.preference_ package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for a while, but was unable to find a preference manager similar to the JFace implementation. So, I ended up creating my own library that originally partially implemented interfaces in the JFace preferences library, but since has deviated.

The library is called [***jpreferences***](https://github.com/erichschroeter/jpreferences) and is hosted on Github.

**EDIT:**
Go figure, when I tried creating a SourceForge project named jpreferences there was a project already by that name. If only I had thought to search for *jpreferences* instead of *preference manager*. Oh well, now anyone looking for what I was looking for has more choices.

Answer (score 0):

You would [find here](http://www.docjar.org/docs2web/s.jsp?q=PreferenceDialog&t=d&start=0) the two main "PreferenceDialog" implementation for big open-source projects.
One of them is much more complete... and is the [`org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog`](http://www.docjar.com/src/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/PreferenceDialog.java) class, in SWT.

I don't know of a similar implementation in Swing, but should I develop one, I would consider using **[XWT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT)** as a more declarative approach to build it, since [XWT isn't linked to eclipse (e4)](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/03/14/e4-relation-between-eclipse-4-1-and-xwt/), and [you can use it with Swing](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/03/02/e4-use-eclipse-4-1-application-platform-but-not-swt/).