# Saving user settings from GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, persistence, preferences

I am currently coding an application, which has an option frame `JDialog`. This frame contains various checkboxes and text fields that the user can configure.

I want to save the changes the user made to the options.

What is the best way of doing so?

My first thought was implementing it by saving it in a file with the format of e.g.

```
checkBox1=value;
textArea1="value";
```

By using the following I could get the field, but I would need to do something like (for the checkbox) myField.isSelected(); which does not work.

```
Field myField = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(name);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object persistence in Java applets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954183/object-persistence-in-java-applets).

Comment: Thanks for the link, didnt found it since I looked for the wrong keywords, duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.util.prefs.Preferences` to store the configuration in your `JDialog`.  This question - [Java Preference Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525248/java-preference-manager) - discuss about how to create frontend+backend solution by using Preferences (something like JFace `org.eclipse.jface.preference`)